# Scrlttr2 custom firsthead

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlttr2

I want to test two header layouts based on the default one. First header without return address in the upper right corner and a centered headline.
[image: header1]

In the second header the return address should start at the same level as the underlined back address with respect to the vertical space.
[image]

I read that `\firsthead` is the right command to create custom headers, but I don't know where I can find a default header skeleton. So I don't know where to start getting all the vertical and horizontal spaces or margins between the objects.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    pagenumber=false,
    parskip=full,
    fontsize=11pt,
    firstfoot=false,
    fromalign=right,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true,
    fromrule=false,
    foldmarks=false,
    enlargefirstpage,
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}   
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myFirstname}{John}
\newcommand{\myFamilyname}{Doe}
\newcommand{\myStreet}{3500 West Olive Avenue}
\newcommand{\myTown}{Burbank, CA 91505-5512}


\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{signature}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\myStreet\\\myTown}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname, \myStreet , \myTown}
\setkomavar{place}{Burbank}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone\,]{(01\,23)\,45\,67\,89\,10}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter\,]{john.doe@email.de}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}



\setkomavar{subject}{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{letter}{Richard M Winsor\\
2192 Lawman Avenue\\ 
Arlington\\
22204 Virginia
}
%
\opening{Dear Mr Winsor,}
%
\blindtext[1]
\noindent \blindtext[4]


\closing{\raggedright Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\firsthead` is deprecated. See `\setkomavar{firsthead}` in the KOMA-Script manual. Examples for heads similar to the shown can be found at the appendix of the [German KOMA-Script book](http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbuch). You can [download the example code from the KOMA-Script Documentation Project](https://komascript.de/komascriptbuch5examples). For horizontal and vertical placement see the pseudo lengths at Part II of either the KOMA-Script book or [the free KOMA-Script manual](http://www.komascript.de/scrguide). You will a large picture and a table with short descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of your address beside the address of the addressee can be done using `fromalign=location`. Unfortunately in this case you cannot use variable `firsthead` to set a headline. But you can use either `scrlayer` or `scrlayer-scrpage` to generate the wanted page head. Here a simple solution with `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    pagenumber=false,
    parskip=full,
    fontsize=11pt,
    fromalign=location,
    firstfoot=false,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true,
    fromrule=false,
    foldmarks=false,
    enlargefirstpage,
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}   
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myFirstname}{John}
\newcommand{\myFamilyname}{Doe}
\newcommand{\myStreet}{3500 West Olive Avenue}
\newcommand{\myTown}{Burbank, CA 91505-5512}


\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{signature}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\myStreet\\\myTown}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname, \myStreet , \myTown}
\setkomavar{place}{Burbank}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone\,]{(01\,23)\,45\,67\,89\,10}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter\,]{john.doe@email.de}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\let\raggedsignature\raggedright

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\chead{\normalfont\Huge\color{red}Headline}
\RedeclarePageStyleAlias{empty}{scrheadings}


\setkomavar{subject}{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{letter}{Richard M Winsor\\
2192 Lawman Avenue\\ 
Arlington\\
22204 Virginia
}
%
\opening{Dear Mr Winsor,}
%
\blindtext[1]
\noindent \blindtext[4]


\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more influence, e.g., to the position of the page head, you should have a look at the `scrlayer` chapter in Part II of the [KOMA-Script manual](http://www.komascript.de/scrguide).

The [German KOMA-Script book](http://www.komascript.de/komascriptbuch) shows a completely different solution in the appendix using `firsthead` for an extended side note. You can adapt that approach to also set the head and only some text beside the addressee.

Or you can use variable `firsthead` for the page head and variable `location` to place your address on your own:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    pagenumber=false,
    parskip=full,
    fontsize=11pt,
    firstfoot=false,
    foldmarks=false,
    enlargefirstpage,
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}   
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myFirstname}{John}
\newcommand{\myFamilyname}{Doe}
\newcommand{\myStreet}{3500 West Olive Avenue}
\newcommand{\myTown}{Burbank, CA 91505-5512}


\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{signature}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\myStreet\\\myTown}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname, \myStreet , \myTown}
\setkomavar{place}{Burbank}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone\,]{(01\,23)\,45\,67\,89\,10}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter\,]{john.doe@email.de}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\let\raggedsignature\raggedright

\usepackage{xcolor}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \centering\Huge\color{red}Headline
}

\setkomavar{location}{%
  \raggedleft
  \usekomavar{fromname}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
}

\setkomavar{subject}{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{letter}{Richard M Winsor\\
2192 Lawman Avenue\\ 
Arlington\\
22204 Virginia
}
%
\opening{Dear Mr Winsor,}
%
\blindtext[1]
\noindent \blindtext[4]


\closing{Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want your address beside the addresse, simply use this second example without `\setkomavar{location}{…}`.

Comment: Are there controls for the width of the location field? If I use a email address like `john.doe@email-america.de` I got a line break in the email address.

Comment: @Hölderlin: Yes. It is controlled by options and pseudo lengths. As told in my comment to the question, you can find the pseudo lengths at Part II of the KOMA-Script manual. See also the description of variable `location`.

Comment: Found it `\@setplength{locwidth}{length }` - thx :)

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
\showfields{address,location}
```

to your preamble you can see that the top of the address field and the top of the location field are aligned:

[image]

The distance from the top of the address field to the baseline of the back address is the pseudolength `backaddrheight`. To align the baseline of the `fromname` in the location field with the baseline of the back address you can use

```
\setkomavar{location}{
  \raggedleft
  \raisebox{0pt}[\useplength{backaddrheight}][\depth]{\usekomavar{fromname}}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
}
```

[image]

Without `visualize` and with header:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,
    pagenumber=false,
    parskip=full,
    fontsize=11pt,
    firstfoot=false,
    fromalign=right,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true,
    fromrule=false,
    foldmarks=false,
    enlargefirstpage
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\myFirstname}{John}
\newcommand{\myFamilyname}{Doe}
\newcommand{\myStreet}{3500 West Olive Avenue}
\newcommand{\myTown}{Burbank, CA 91505-5512}

\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{signature}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\myStreet\\\myTown}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname, \myStreet , \myTown}
\setkomavar{place}{Burbank}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone\,]{(01\,23)\,45\,67\,89\,10}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter\,]{john.doe@email.de}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\setkomavar{subject}{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{\centering\Huge \textcolor{red}{HEADLINE}}
\setkomavar{location}{
  \raggedleft
  \raisebox{0pt}[\useplength{backaddrheight}][\depth]{\usekomavar{fromname}}\\
  \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\
  \usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}
}

% to visualize the position and the size of address and location:
%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
%\showfields{address,location}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Richard M Winsor\\
2192 Lawman Avenue\\ 
Arlington\\
22204 Virginia
}
\opening{Dear Mr Winsor,}
\blindtext[1]
\noindent \blindtext[4]
\closing{\raggedright Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```